# Warnings 5 and 32 on first two files while renaming all files in a directory

Tags: php, image, warnings, file-rename

I made a simple image renaming application. It adds a number serially after every image name to distinguish one from another. But the problem is that, when this PHP application runs I get two warnings and I think for this reason `$i` value is starting with 3, like image 3, image 4….

[image]
But I want it to start it with 1. Like image 1, image 2….

And the warning I got is

[image]

So my question is:

1. Why are these warnings generated?
2. How to execute this PHP code without getting any warnings?

   $dir='c:/xampp/htdocs/practice/haha/';
       echo getcwd().'';
       $i=1;
       if(is_dir($dir)){
       echo dirname($dir);
            $file=opendir($dir);

   ```
    while(($data=readdir($file))!==false){
     $info=pathinfo($data,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
       echo $data;
        //echo pathinfo($data,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'</br>';
        //echo basename(pathinfo($data,PATHINFO_BASENAME),'.jpg').'</br>';
        rename($dir.$data,$dir.'mat '.$i.'.jpg');
         echo $i.'</br>';
        $i++;

    }
   ```

   }

Comment: Are any of these files named `Halloween 1.jpg` to start with, or are there any other files by that name in the folder? Are there any other programs accessing the original files?

Comment: they have random names and located in a directory in my root php htdocs folder.I want to give them a common name with a distinguish feature.No other programme is using them

Comment: You have full permission of root folder?

Comment: problem is `haha//Halloween`, you are using `haha/` then adding `/Halloween` which is making wrong path. use `/` only at once place.

Comment: @Himanshu i corrected that .But problem still exists :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude the implicit `.` and `..` automatic directory entries from the loop, since they can't be renamed anyway. That's where the errors are coming from; the `.` (current directory) is of course in use in your own code, and `..` (parent directory) can't be renamed when a child is open.